# Using System path in Spring Boot application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In the actual production and development servers, the base path is set with the code below.

```
private static String FILE_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "FILES";
```

I want to move this code to application.properties.

Is there a way to use a path like System.getProperty in application.properties?

Sorry for such a novice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following in `application.yml` and it worked.

```
filedir: ${user.dir}${file.separator}FILES
```

And then

```
@Value("${filedir}")
private String fileDir;
```

Please let me know it it wrks for you.

Comment: ${user.dir} worked very successfully.

Unfortunately ${file.separator=='\\' ?/:\\} didn't work, but ${file.separator} worked instead.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I voted up your answer. But edit it please. Note that `${file.separator}` is enough.